# R: Use brackets in Expression

Tags: r, expression, brackets

I'd like to have my xlab looking like this (with the 2 shifted up):

Accumulated area [km^2]

With this expression code I managed to get the right text, but I can't use brackets for some reason.

```
xlab(expression(Accumulated ~ area ~ (km^{2})))
```

Which leads to: Accumulated area (km^2)

Does someone know how I can use brackets instead of parentheses?

Comment: For me, this worked: `plot( c(1,2), xlab=expression(Accumulated ~ area ~ "["~km ^2~"]") )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the latex2exp package to obtain what you need.  The following toy example might serve you.  Also, it is worth exploring this package as it has some functionalities that you might find useful.

```
library(latex2exp)

x <- rnorm(5, mean=2.5, sd=1.1)
y <- rnorm(5, mean=2.5, sd=1.1)

windows()

plot(x,y, xlab=TeX(r'($\[km^2\]$)'))
```